# Sending stdout as response from CGI spawned program

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I'm trying to compose a .zip file in a CGI program and send that as the content response.  I'm getting stuck in  that whenever I spawn a program that prints to stdout, that somehow doesn't get accepted by Apache.  It seems to be something to do with spawning a program that writes to stdout.  The snippet below reproduces this problem.  I always get the following error form Apache:

```
malformed header from script. Bad header=hello world  

print ("Content-Type: text/html");  
print ("");  
#print ("hello world");     <-----This works  
os.system("echo hello world");  <-----This doesn't work
```

It works fine if I just print the string from my CGI script.  If I run it with either statement from the command line, there's no difference in behaviour.  Is there something special I need to do to get the stdout from a spawned program out as my respone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sys.stdout.flush()` before calling external programs.